# Way to find angle between plane and line without using vectors?

Tags: geometry

Let $\alpha$ be a given plane and let $m$ and $n$ be two perpendicular lines on the plane. Suppose a line $l$ makes an angle of $60^0$ degress with line $m$ and $45^0$ degrees with line $n$. How can we find the angle between $l$ and the plane $\alpha$ without using vectors??

Comment: $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma = 1$ should work.

Comment: Note that in that formula, the three angles are the angle with $m$, the angle with $n$, and the angle with the perpendicular line through $m$ and $n$. Once you find that third angle, it's the complement of the angle between line $l$ and the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments already contain an answer. In order to derive that answer, I'll use vectors, even though the final result is without them.

Consider a local coordinate system, with $x$ and $y$ axes in the direction of $m$ resp. $n$, and the $z$ axis perpendicular to $\alpha$. Then the direction vector of $l$ has length $\sqrt{l_x^2+l_y^2+l_z^2}$. Each of these coordinates is the projection of $l$ onto the respective axis. The projection onto an axis is the length of the vector times the cosine of the angle it makes with the axis. If we assume that the direction vector of $l$ has length $1$, we get $1=\sqrt{\cos^2\mu+\cos^2\nu+\cos^2\theta}$ where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the angles $l$ makes with $m$ resp. $n$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the $z$ direction and $l$. (Perhaps it is a bit unfortunate that you named the plane $\alpha$, because that makes naming the angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ a bit confusing.) You may square the equation and get

$$\cos^2\mu+\cos^2\nu+\cos^2\theta=1\;.$$

As $z$ was chosen orthogonal to $\alpha$, the angle $\varphi$ between the line and the plane is complementary to $\theta$, i.e. $\varphi=90°-\theta$. So $\cos\theta=\sin\varphi$ and

$$\varphi=\arcsin\sqrt{1-\cos^2\mu-\cos^2\nu}$$

Note that taking the positive square root will lead to a positive angle. Taking the negative square root assumes that the $z$ direction is pointing in the other direction perpendicular to $\alpha$, leading to negative angles.